# How can I upload code on Github without installing Git on my laptop?

Tags: git, github

I want just to upload code on Github so that it can be publically available in the form of URL. So can it be done without installing Git ? If it can be , can anybody please mention the steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your beef with git ?

Comment: I'm new to Git and this question might  be very lame.Could you please explain why is it important to install Git if we do not need our version control for the code. Is there any alternative to upload code online ?

Comment: Why use github if you do not want to use git?  Wouldn't Dropbox do?

Comment: GitHub is a web interface built around a version control system. It makes no sense to use the interface without also using a VCS.

Answer (score 8):

GitHub added a feature that allows uploading files through the website.

[Here's their blog post with the details](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories)

It involves going to your repository and clicking on the button 'upload files' near the clone button.

Answer (score 4):

use this URL according to your account (after login)

`https://github.com/yourname/yourrepositoryname/upload/master`

and then drag and drop your files

Answer (score 0):

You could use GitHub's Api. Assuming you have already a repo, you can make commits via HTTP POST requests. Take a look on this link: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit

You might need some additional steps, like authentication first, so I recommend to see the GitHub's API complete documentation here: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Answer (score 0):

Major problem is that currently there is no web interface available to create master branch in newly created repo. Here is alternate option.

1. Find empty repo having master branch like [this](https://github.com/demeyere/empty)
2. Fork this repository using 'Fork' button
3. Upload files by clicking on 'Upload Files' button or simply follow [this](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories) tutorial
4. You can also change repository name from 'Settings' tab of this repository

Answer (score -3):

Each GitHub repo has a "Download ZIP" link.

Comment: you misunderstood the question mate!

Comment: Not sure, it depends to what "it" refers to in "it can be publically available in the form of URL". To me it was pretty obvious that the OP wanted the ability to make the code available to non-git users. If it's not the case, then why the user wants to use GitHub is beyond me, but never mind.

Comment: Sure, but to have a public url you need to upload the code first, and - imo -  this is what the op wants to know.